# error displaying connection information

Tags: networking

I am a new user in Ubuntu Linux 
I am facing this problem about the network
I can't see the **connection information**
when I click on it returns **error displaying connection information**

[image]

and when I click on **Edit connections**:

[image]

How can it be that I have no connection yet I am browsing the INTERNET at the same time?

I have used a terminal command to make a pppoe connection which is the type of INTERNET connection I have

```
sudo pon dsl-provider
```

I need to know my IP and how to make a share folder.

Comment: If you want to know your local ip address use: `ifconfig` or `ip a` commands. If you need to know your public ip: `curl ifconfig.co` or search the web: 'what is my ip' or check your router.

Comment: What about `ip a`? Use `ifconfig -a` instead of `ifconfig`.

Comment: well thank you Ravexina 
I have try ifconfig it gives nothing about the IP
my pc connected to a network the network have a DHCP 
the internet is a broadband pppoe
I am sure there is some thing wrong